# Period in a Filename recognizing as extension

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have an admin page that can upload files into my database, the problem is whenever the file has a period (.) on it's name, the script reads it as an extension. For example: I upload a file named "flower1.1.jpg" it became as "flower1.1" without the jpg extension.
My php upload script:

```
<?php

function upload_file()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))
    {
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);
        $new_name = $extension[0] . '.' . $extension[1];
        $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $new_name;
    }
}

function get_image_name($user_id)
{
    include('db3.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT image FROM users1 WHERE id = '$user_id'");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        return $row["image"];
    }
}

function get_total_all_records()
{
    include('db3.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users1");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you even trying to get an extension? You're just exploding and concating them back together again:

```
function upload_file()
{
    if ( isset($_FILES["user_image"]) )
    {
        $destination = './upload/' . $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    }
}
```

As a word of caution, check to make sure your users are uploading only images:

```
function upload_file()
{
    static $valid_formats = array(
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif'
    );

    if ( isset($_FILES['user_image']) )
    {
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime = $finfo->file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name']);

        if ( !in_array($mime, $valid_formats) )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
        }

        $destination = './upload/' . $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your first code and it doesnt work, it doesnt recognize the $new_name; function

Comment: @AppleJohn Yeah, `$new_name` doesn't exist anymore. A small typo on my part. Simply return `$_FILES['user_image']['name']`.